# dequeueReusableCell() vs UITableViewCell()

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm implementing search with autofill. I have `UITextField` and `UITableView`. When user changes text in text field I'm loading new data from server and displaying it in table view.
Number of results is fixed(5 or less). Height of table is connected to number of results, so it will never scroll. When new results arrive i simply call `reloadData()` for table.

So the question is should i use `dequeueReusableCell()`  or create new cells with `UITableViewCell()`, as they will never reuse? Will `reloadData()` clear all memory for cells if they were created without dequeuing?

Comment: If you use UITableViewCell() means you are using default cell which tableView has and it has many limitations , and using dequeueReusableCell() is always a better deal , you can customize your tableViewCell as you want.

Comment: @Vikky as I need cells for displaying simple text, default cells are ok.

Comment: Yes you are correct for simple text default cells are OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of `dequeueReusableCell()` is to reuse the `UITableViewCell` that is created already in memory, instead of recreating it, therefore, it runs faster on the CPU than having to recreate a `UITableViewCell` each time you need one. It has nothing to do with the content you give it.

So it's always preferable to use `dequeueReusableCell()` as it makes the app run smoother. Even if the difference is negligible.

Comment: If I reload table, cells will be recreated anyways, or no?

Comment: No, even when you reload, cells will be reused

Comment: @Helldog cells will only be created when the OS doesn't find enough created cells to be displayed on the screen. If in one of your previous search results you have 5 cells, and in your newer search results you have 3, nothing new will be used. But if your first search results were 3, and then 5, 2 new ones will be created.